# How to upgrade version of Nodejs in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

Firebase CLI v11.0.0 is incompatible with Node.js v12.21.0 Please upgrade Node.js to version >= 14.18.0

I did every possible thing, including reinstalling and npm i node@14.18.0 but failed to upgrade my node js version

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I Also Have Same Problem But After Search  found that i have Heroku install on my device which install node of old version

1. uninstall node.
2. try node -v in cmd
3. if you get version than their is another node install
4. found location of that node by search in window search

This Help me

> uninstall Heroku

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:\Program Files\nodejs and delete existing `nodejs` folder
2. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/download to download the newest version or to https://nodejs.org/dist/ to download any specific version needed

Another way is to use nvm as described here: https://codeburst.io/nvm-for-windows-how-to-install-and-use-13b7a4209791

Answer (score -1):

You can use this one:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: tried , but not working

Comment: npm install [package-name]@[version-number] try this one...

Comment: npm install node@14.18.0 even after running this command, node version is currently showing 12.2.0. it's not upgrading.

Comment: this doesn't work on windows

Comment: It worked for me though, and I am on windows. You could also try NVM